# Structuring Firebase DB

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I recently started using firebase and am trying to remodel my data in a NoSql way in my Android application. My current structure is MIX --- > MIXTITLE ----> MIXDETAILS (All the details for this mix). A lot of structures I have seen order items by a UID but how do I then relate that to users and avoid having a bunch of duplicate records per user ?

For example the user is able to add songs to a library and that library has three tabs one for all songs, on for playlists and one for favorites. Storing MIX by UID would not let me query find all MIXES where that mix has been added to the users library.

Would a better approach be to denormalize the data and create a USERMIX node that lists all MIX under User UID ?

Comment: UID stands for User Id. UID is how Firebase tracks authenticated users internally i.e. when a user is created, they are assigned a UID and that uid can then be used to create your own /users node where you can store additional information about each user /users/uid_0  and  /users/uid_1 etc. If you want to create unique keys to store other kinds of data, that's usually accomplished via childByAutoId() (swift) or push(). Without more information about your use case and platform in your question we're not going to be able to provide much more info,

Comment: Modeling data in Firebase is a very broad topic. The best model is the one that works for your use-cases. This is sort of non-advice, but actually extremely important: in NoSQL you often end up augmenting your data model for your app's use-cases. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood it may be like this for an example.

```
allSongs
- sid1
- sid2
..
users
- uid1
- uid2
..
favorites
-uid1
--sid1:true
--sid5:true
..
playlists
-uid1
--sid2:true
--sid7:true
--sid12:true
..
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer ! I actually had a follow up question to this. How would I nest objects in this structure for example instead of all songs -- > songId wouldn't it make sense to have it be songs ---> UID ----> songId ---> SongDetails. If so how would I insert this into the database without creating an object just to hold the song Id and add a song object to that object ?

Comment: better to store songs only with songId. adding uid node to songs may lead to duplication of songs. better structure is songs->songid->songObject. you can insert songObject by songsRef.child(""songId").setValue(SongObject).